# Clear array that is used in subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Suppose I have a component like this:

```
export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {
  orders: OrderCardModel[] = [];
  query = "";
  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService, private preloader: PreloaderService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getOrderCards();
  }

  getOrderCards(): any {
    this.preloader.showPreloader();
    this.sharedService.getInActiveOrderCards(this.query).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.preloader.hidePreloader())
    )
      .subscribe(element: any) => {
        const newOrderCards = element.data.map((d: any) => 
          new OrderCardModel(
            d.id,
            d.deviceName,
            d.groupName,
            d.projectName,
            new Date(d.dateToWarehouse),
            new Date(d.dateToRelease),
          )
        );
        this.orders = [...newOrderCards, ...this.orders];
      })
  }

  queryFilter(event: string) {
    this.query = event;
    this.orders = [];
    this.getOrderCards();
  }
}
```

I expect that program would works like this:

1. When the page is open the `getOrderCards()` should run.
2. The page shows loaded cards.
3. The page has search input where we can put `query` string.
4. When user put something in search input the `queryFilter` should clear orders array.
5. Program once again fetch data from server with query parameter.

ad 1. - works as I expect
ad 2. - works as I expect
ad 3. - works as I expect
ad 4. - When internet is slow 3G I noticed that the `queryFilter` method doesn't work as I would expect, I mean that the orders didn't clear and have the previous data plus the data from point 5.
ad 5. - works as I expect

When I add to my component new variable `subscription` and unsubscribe it in `queryFilter` the program runs as I expect, but I do not know is it the proper way.

```
export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {
  orders: OrderCardModel[] = [];
  query = "";
  subscription = new Subscription();
  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService, private preloader: PreloaderService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getOrderCards();
  }

  getOrderCards(): any {
    this.preloader.showPreloader();
    this.subscription = this.sharedService.getInActiveOrderCards(this.query).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.preloader.hidePreloader())
    )
      .subscribe(element: any) => {
        const newOrderCards = element.data.map((d: any) => 
          new OrderCardModel(
            d.id,
            d.deviceName,
            d.groupName,
            d.projectName,
            new Date(d.dateToWarehouse),
            new Date(d.dateToRelease),
          )
        );
        this.orders = [...newOrderCards, ...this.orders];
      })
  }

  queryFilter(event: string) {
    this.query = event;
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    this.orders = [];
    this.getOrderCards();
  }
}
```

So my question: how should I clear that orders array?

Edit. 1
If I store subscriptions like this:

```
subscription = new Subscription();
  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService, private preloader: PreloaderService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getOrderCards();
  }

  getOrderCards(): any {
    this.preloader.showPreloader();
    this.subscription.add(this.sharedService.getActiveOrderCards(this.page++, this.pageSize, this.query).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.preloader.hidePreloader()),
    )
      .subscribe((element: any) => {
        this.orders = [...this.orders, ...element.data.map((d: any) => new OrderCardModel(
          d.id,
          d.deviceName,
          d.groupName,
          d.projectName,
          new Date(d.dateToWarehouse),
          new Date(d.dateToRelease),
          d.reciver,
          d.itemsCount,
          d.finishedItemsCount,
          Number(d.state)
        )
        )];
      }));
  }

  showMore() {
    this.getOrderCards();
  }

  onScroll() {
    this.getOrderCards();
  }

  queryFilter(event: string) {
    this.query = event;
    this.page = 0;
    console.log(this.subscription);
    this.orders = [];
    this.getOrderCards();
  }
```

the `console.log` from `queryFilter` print something like this:

```
Subscription {closed: false, _parentOrParents: null, _subscriptions: Array(0)}
closed: false
_parentOrParents: null
_subscriptions: []
[[Prototype]]: Object
Subscription {closed: false, _parentOrParents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1)}
closed: false
_parentOrParents: null
_subscriptions: []
[[Prototype]]: Object
Subscription {closed: false, _parentOrParents: null, _subscriptions: Array(2)}
closed: false
_parentOrParents: null
_subscriptions: []
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Maybe I am wrong but this looks like subscriptions are stacked because previous subscription isn't complete and another subscription is created and then if I run `this.orders = []` it is cleared but in the background, unfinished subscription is pushing values to `orders`.

Edit. 2 I've prepared some example, I hope you can easly reproduce my error.
[This is the link to stackblitz where you can test my solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m5csb5?file=src/main.ts)

[image: the result how program works]

Comment: You don't need a subscription for an observable that completes (I am assuming you are using httpClient). Also, why are you spreading the orders Array? Why not simply overwrite it in getOrderCards?

Comment: Exactly, I use httpClient. What about if my observable is not complete? I think that is my problem that I try to clear orders that is inside subscribe that is not complete.

Comment: Your observables always completes (success or error) so that's not the issue. Your problem is this.orders = [...newOrderCards, ...this.orders]; why not this.orders=newOrderCards ?

Comment: I use spread array because in my page I use inifinite scroll pagination and every scroll I want to add new items to existing orders but if user put something in query I want clear orders.

Comment: this.orders = []; should be enough. How are you using the orders array in your template? This looks like a change detection problem.

Comment: The template shows orders by *ngFor but for pagination I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll I will check detection problem, thank for advice.

Comment: @Tim I've added more description, please check it out if you want.

Comment: Where is your code for inifinite scroll pagination and every scroll?

Comment: I am not sure about the infinite scroll, but this is roughly how I would have implemented this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chphpi?file=src/app/components/order/order.component.ts

Comment: I think the infinite scroll is not a problem, without it there is also issue.

Comment: Please see my example from Edit.2